# How can I check whether an argument passed to a shell script is NOT an integer?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, arguments

I know how to check whether an argument is an integer using:

```sh
if [[ $2 = *[[:digit:]]* ]]; then
    # $2 is a number
else
    # $2 is not a number
fi
```

However, I need to check whether the argument is *not* a integer. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$2 = *[[:digit:]]*` only checks whether `$2` *contains* a digit.

```
# is an integer
[[ $2 =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]
# is not an integer
[[ ! $2 =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]
```

Comment: This command doesn't work, keep getting a 'syntax error near unexpected token' error! In fact the only command that works is the one I used initially.

Comment: @user2232423 near unexpected token *what*?

Answer (score 3):

### A POSIX-compliant approach

A robust and portable (POSIX-compliant; tested in `dash`) approach is to check whether the shell can parse the variable as an integer, as demonstrated in the script below.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# test-int.sh
# A script that tests whether its first argument is an integer

if [ "$1" -eq 0 -o "$1" -ne 0 ] >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    printf "integer: %s\n" "$1"
else
    printf "not an integer\n"
fi
```

### Tests

```
$ dash test-int.sh foo
not an integer
$ dash test-int.sh 098234
integer: 098234
$ dash test-int.sh 77239asdfasf
not an integer
$ dash test-int.sh -77239
integer: -77239
```

Note that this approach also accepts negative integers out of the box, but you can easily modify it to only accept positive integers, for instance.

In my script, a successfully parsed integer is printed as a *string*, but, alternatively, you may want to print it as an *integer*, with `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy you know . You can do this :

```
   if echo $Myvar | egrep -q '^[0-9]+$'; then
      # $Myvar is a number
   else
      # $Myvar is not a number
   fi
```

This is some thing that i predominantly use for a number check.

Answer (score 0):

You test only checks whether the input is a digit; for example is $2 is "43" then this will print:
43 is not a number
Fixing your solution to check for actual numbers can be done with a regular expression:

```
if [[ $2 =~ ^-?[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
    echo "$2 is a number"
fi
```

Checking whether the input is not a number is then just a matter of negating the test:

```
if [[ ! $2 =~ ^-?[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
    echo "$2 is not a number"
fi
```